# Character animations in flutter (like Unity 3D)

Tags: flutter, 3d, 2d, flutter-animation

Dears, I'm looking into a efficient method to manage different animationsfor a character. This animations will be: talking, thinking, idle, move right/left arm, and others. Any idea to manage this? And maybe having more than one animation at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter does not support 3d animation yet (Rive is there). you can do complex 2d animation in flutter. But A scenario like you described is recommended to do through Rive or a similar tool.

I created a small app to demonstrate a basic text animation in flutter.

This is the DartPad link

https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true&id=1a28bdd9203250d3226cc25d512579ec

I think this will be helpful to start your journey.

Answer (score 0):

**Flutter Above v3 Support Everything**

[flutter_embed_unity: ^1.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_embed_unity)

For Further Explanation, Follow the plugin guidelines.

Answer (score -1):

Checkout [rive](https://rive.app/).

The tool should be useful to you.
It was also built with flutter